# As an admin user, how can I use the bitbucket REST API to view the email addresses of all the users in my workspace?

Tags: python, bitbucket-api

I tried the following api calls:

`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/workspaces/<workspace_name>/members`

followed by self.href for each member.

I can only see their UUID and display name not their emails. I have admin rights to the workspace, how can I view emails of members?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. They already raise a request to their developer team.
Check this out https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22643

Give a vote on the ticket if you need this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Its not available via API yes, but is available via browser.

[https://bitbucket.org/{your_workspace}/workspace/settings/user-directory](https://bitbucket.org/%7Byour_workspace%7D/workspace/settings/user-directory) -> Export in top right hand corner will give you

The above calls the URL [https://bitbucket.org/!api/internal/workspaces/{your_workspace}/user-list](https://bitbucket.org/!api/internal/workspaces/%7Byour_workspace%7D/user-list)  - don't think it's exposed as an API separately yet.